# Data getting lost in the memory c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, matrix

So I made a matrix from triple pointers, thats like matrix that has pointers to another class. In the constructor I allocate the memory, but when the constructor ends all the data gets lost in memory. What am I doing wrong?
This is my class

```
class Map {
  Field*** f;
  int rows;
  int columns;

 public:
  Map(int rows_, int columns_) : rows(rows_), columns(columns_) {
    Field*** f;
    f = new Field**[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      f[i] = new Field*[columns];
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        f[i][j] = new Field;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In `Map` constructor, you are declaring a local variable named `f`, then initializing it. Then that variable goes out of scope and the memory it points to is leaked. The data member, also named `f`, is never initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this from your constructor:

```
Field ***f;
```

That is local to the constructor body and shadows the member. When constructed the local f goes out of scope and you are left with memory leak.